# Override blog intro image

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, overrides

While trying to override the way the intro images are displayed in blog layout (I want to add a class to the images), I run into this code in `templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php`:

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

What's the best/correct way to override this and control how my intro-images are displayed?

Comment: See template overrides at [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would want to match the path that you send as the first parameter within your template at `templates/*your_template*/html/layouts/`

So in the example you listed of `<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>` copy the file currently at `layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php` to `templates/*your_template*/html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php` and it should use the version in your template instead of the default layout.