# Picture in article as Read More-link

Tags: joomla-3.x

This might be a very silly question but google is not helping me. What I would like is to add the 'read more' attribute to a picture in my article. I have no clue how I should go about this, or where to start. I hope someone can give me some directions

Comment: do you mean to have the article intro image in a blog layout be link to the full article? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/layout-overrides-intro-image-link/5253#5253  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4051/override-blog-intro-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The simplest way to achieve this would be to copy the article link and add the link to the article to the image inside your article (i.e. post the article, grab the link, then go back to the article and add the link to any image that will display above your "read more" line).
2. Another way would be to create a template override for the component you are using for your articles. If you are using the default Joomla! Content component (com_content), then your template overrides would be stored in: `/templates/[YOUR_THEME]/html/com_content/...` (Your most likely looking for `.../category/category.php`). Again, you could programmatically add a link to your "Intro Image" to the actual article.
3. If you want the "Read More" link/image to be the same image for every article, then you could modify the CSS of your template so that the image is the background for the button. Then every time the "read more" button is added, the image is used.

Comment: It's not the same image everytime, unfortunately.
If i use option 1, I do think I have to also add the 'Read More' <hr> element, right?

Comment: It all depends on how you are setting up your categories, but I would venture to say you'll need the "read more" line in your articles regardless of what option you use.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that same conclusion also because otherwise I don't have a seperation between intro and content :) I think it'll have to do with the link, and I'll use your tip-1 as an extra. Thank you!

Comment: Your're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 'read more' to appear not in text but over a graphic, you'd need to create CSS for that. I've seen this done with sliders, a Joomla extension like those from Shape5 where the text appears over the graphic. You could examine that for how the CSS for it is done and apply it to your situation.